# Besides specific evolutions, which benefits are there for making my Pokemon happy?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

Is there any reason, besides specific evolutions of some Pokemon that I need to make them happy?

Do their moves get stronger the happier they are?

Is there a quest that I will miss out on if some of my Pokemon don't have maxed happy stats?

Can I just ignore the fact the happiness factor of my Pokemon?

Comment: Outside of version-specific things, certain moves are influenced by the happiness mechanic such as Return and Frustration. Return scales positively with happiness, dealing maximum damage at maximum happiness, whereas Frustration deals scales inversely with happiness, dealing maximum damage at minimum happiness.

Comment: Out of universe, you might enjoy it.

Comment: Note that 'Happiness' is different to 'Affection', which is the number of hearts your Pokemon has in Pokemon Refresh (previously Pokemon Amie in XY/ORAS) - which itself conveys different bonuses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most moves are not affected by happiness, but the move [Return](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Return_(move)) does more damage based on happiness. It has has a linear formula with 1 base power at no happiness and 102 base power at max happiness. Conversely, [Frustration](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Frustration_(move)) does less as a Pokemon is happier. The base power scale is the reverse of Return.

In order to Move Tutor various moves, such as [Draco Meteor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Draco_Meteor_(move)) in Pokemon Sun and Moon, the Pokemon needs max happiness. This has occurred in [previous games](http://pokemondb.net/mechanics/move-tutors). For reference, moves which have required max happiness to tutor in ORAS include Blast Burn, Draco Meteor, Fire Pledge, Frenzy Plant, Grass Pledge, Hydro Cannon and Water Pledge.

Occasionally, there are specific in game items that depend on happiness. An example is the Footprint Ribbon given by [Dr. Footprint](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dr._Footstep) for max Happiness in Gen IV games. I am currently unaware of any such items in Pokemon Sun and Moon.

Comment: Up-voted for inclusion of Move Tutor moves, though for completeness, it might be worth including the base power calculation @pinckerman included in their answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably only two moves: [Return and Frustration](http://www.serebii.net/games/returnfrust.shtml).

Two unique moves in that the damage utilised is proportionally based upon how much the Pokémon likes its trainer. This is done utilising the *Happiness Value* of the Pokémon.

The *Happiness Value* is always a number between 0 and 255 and as such, the figure of this is utilised within the formula that calculates the damage.

**Return:**

> Base Power = Pokémon Happiness / 2.5

This gives a maximum result of 102 and a minimum result of 1.

**Frustration:**

> Base Power = (255 - Pokémon Happiness) / 2.5

This gives a maximum result of 102 and a minimum result of 1.

Answer (score 0):

first sorry for my bad school english:

Are you only referring to pure Happiness or also to the "Heart-Rating" you can get for petting your Pokemon and feeding them. 
If so, there is also the possibility for your Pokemon to dodge attacks sometimes or survive with 1HP left if their Hearts are all filled.

Angzuril is completly right about Happiness/Friendship.

Also: Walking makes your Pokemon Happy and so does nearly everything except giving them bitter medication, so if you have your team set and carry it around with you, you are about to max their Happiness with no extra effort. 
(Every 128 Steps a 50% Chance for Happiness +1)

Source: http://www.pokewiki.de/Freundschaft (Sadly it is a german page, I hope that is allowed)