# Why is my Pokémon getting buffs?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have elvolved my Munchlax into a Snorlax. I know that you need max friendship level to evolve him.

Once in a while, during battle with him, he will do certain actions like dodge an attack, and it seems like certain moves have better critical hit rates. When ever this happens hearts come out of him which leads me to believe it's because of the friendship level. What is the cause of these effects during the battle?

I've looked through the [wiki page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship) on friendship, but the only thing about moves mentioned is

> ...the power of **Return** and **Frustration**...

There seems to be nothing mentioned abut generation VII at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Besides specific evolutions, which benefits are there for making my Pokemon happy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292135/besides-specific-evolutions-which-benefits-are-there-for-making-my-pokemon-happ)

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer that questin is about friendship. This question is *actually* about Affection being mistaken as the same as friendship. The title makes it seem like a dupe, but it's actually not.

Comment: @Vemonus If the question is "Is friendship doing this?", then it's a duplicate. If the question is "What are the benefits of affection?", then it's not. Right now, it's the former.

Comment: I honestly didn't know they were different I will fix the title.

Comment: Changing the body of the question in response to receiving an answer is not the greatest thing.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer my question still stands though. I was just confused by the differance between friendship and happiness. should i create a whole new question?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I believe was what you were trying to ask. Let me know if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Friendship* is still present in 7th gen, you need that to evolve Munchlax to Snorlax, as you have experienced.

[Pokemon Refresh](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Refresh), instead, affects *Affection*, which has nothing to do with friendship.

**EDIT:**

Regarding *Affection* benefits, you get different send-in, waiting and switch-out dialogues and Pokemon in-battle animations.

The Affection benefits in Pokémon Refresh remain largely the same as in [Pokémon-Amie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon-Amie#Affection_benefits):

> A Pokémon with high levels of Affection will gain certain bonuses in battle and will interact with its Trainer in unique ways.
>
> - At Affection level 2 and higher, a Pokémon will gain 1.2 times the normal experience from battles.
> - At Affection level 3 and higher, a Pokémon may endure attacks that could otherwise make it faint and survive with 1 HP (including
>     confusion damage). This can activate multiple times per turn.
> - At Affection level 4 and higher, a Pokémon can sometimes:
>
>   - Avoid attacks, even when they have 100% accuracy. This can activate multiple times per turn.
>   - Shake off status conditions at the end of the turn.
> - At Affection level 5 and higher, a Pokémon can sometimes have higher chance of critical hits.
>
> An Affection level of 2 or higher is also a prerequisite to evolve *Eevee* into *Sylveon*. (The other requirement is that *Eevee* must know a Fairy-type move when it levels up).
>
> There are some cases where Pokémon do not get their Affection bonuses, however. 
>   More broadly, battles conducted over wireless or online play, do not incorporate any Affection benefits.

Also, here's a summary table:

[image]

Comment: so is affection only changing the dialogue? or is it actually giving me a greater chance of surviving a hit with 1 HP or dodging a move?

Comment: @Buzz The affection affects everything you see in the above table. A bigger affection gives a greater chance of those special events to happen.

Comment: @Buzz Improved benefits part

Comment: The dialogues are slightly different in SM, or at least in Sun.

Comment: @Nolonar Bulbapedia is probably not fully updated yet.

Comment: Does this mean that affection is relevant in competitive online battles? Should we be giving Pokemon attention before challenging friends?

Comment: @PhilD. No, like Pokemon-Amie battles conducted over wireless or online play do not incorporate any Affection benefits. You get benefits only in wild battles and against in-game trainers.

Comment: @pinckerman I thought that would be weird but the distinction wasn't made. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @PhilD. You're right, I should add that to my answer