# What do Poké Beans do?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

What is the purpose of Poké Beans? Like does feeding one bean increase any stat of my Pokémon like speed or attack?

Answer (score 3):

PokeBeans have several effects, for example:

1. Increase the affection of the Pokemon (Regular bean = 3 points; Patterned bean = 5 points)
2. Have certain effects if put into the boxes in Poke Pelago
3. They are used to develop islands in Poke Pelago

The effects are as the following:

- Isle Abeens: The spawnrate of wild pokemon is increased
- Isle Aplenny: The growth time of berries is cut in half
- Isle Aphun: The time needed to finish an exploration is cut in half
- Isle Evelup: The time needed for training is cut in half
- Isle Avue: Increases the gained happiness.

Every bean lasts for a specific time: a regular bean will last for 30 minutes, a patterned bean for 1 hour and a rainbow bean for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Feeding a Pokémon a Poké Bean will increase that Pokémon's affection. Patterned and rainbow Poké Beans will increase affection more than normal Poké Beans.

For the effects of affection, [check out this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/294492/143571).

Answer (score 0):

Feeding PokeBeans to your pokemon will increase there affection towards you, which in turn can trigger certain evolutions(Eevee evolves into Sylveon with 2 hears and 1 fairy move. [link](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Methods_of_evolution)

The second, and for most players the more important use of Pokebeans is that the reduce the time of all [Poké Pelago](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Pelago) actions.
It will cut the growth time of berries, it will reduce the time pokemon need on trainings and it will reduce the expedition caves.

Comment: 1 Fairy move is enough.